# No handlers could be found for logger "pubnub" Error when asking for message

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pubnub

I am using pubnub at the moment. I am sending some messages to my pubnub account (status:on and status:off) but when I want to run my python script on my raspberry pi. I get this error.

No handlers could be found for logger "pubnub"

I have the newest python version
I have the newest pubnub version

code:

```
from pubnub.pnconfiguration import PNConfiguration
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub
from pubnub.callbacks import SubscribeCallback
from pubnub.enums import PNOperationType, PNStatusCategory
from pubnub.pubnub import PubNub, SubscribeListener
import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

pnconf = PNConfiguration()
pnconf.subscribe_key = "sub-c-e1af6266-e1d0-11e7-ad36-deb77ae39924"
pnconf.publish_key = "pub-c-6dbd1d39-2915-4df0-b99a-5b358cf69209"
pnconf.ssl = True
pubnub = PubNub(pnconf)

def my_publish_callback(envelope, status):
    # Check whether request successfully completed or not
    if not status.is_error():
        pass  # Message successfully published to specified channel.
    else:
        pass  # Handle message publish error. Check 'category' property to find out possible issue
        # because of which request did fail.
        # Request can be resent using: [status retry];

class MySubscribeCallback(SubscribeCallback):
    def presence(self, pubnub, presence):
        pass  # handle incoming presence data

    def status(self, pubnub, status):
        if status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNUnexpectedDisconnectCategory:
            pass  # This event happens when radio / connectivity is lost

        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNConnectedCategory:
            # Connect event. You can do stuff like publish, and know you'll get it.
            # Or just use the connected event to confirm you are subscribed for
            # UI / internal notifications, etc
            pubnub.publish().channel("led").message("hello!!").async(my_publish_callback)
        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNReconnectedCategory:
            pass
            # Happens as part of our regular operation. This event happens when
            # radio / connectivity is lost, then regained.
        elif status.category == PNStatusCategory.PNDecryptionErrorCategory:
            pass
            # Handle message decryption error. Probably client configured to
            # encrypt messages and on live data feed it received plain text.

    def message(self, pubnub, message):
        print(message.message)
        if 'status' in message.message:
            print(message.message['status'])
            whatToDo(message.message['status'])
        pass  # Handle new message stored in message.message

def whatToDo(status):
    if status == 'ON':
        print('Switch ON light')
        # switch on
        led.on()
    else:
        print('Swtich OFF light')
        # switch off
        led.off()

pubnub.add_listener(MySubscribeCallback())
pubnub.subscribe().channels('led').execute()
```

Comment: Is it an error or a **warning**?

Comment: This is typically just to let you know that the module/package mentioned is trying to log some messages using the builtin `logging` module and that you don't have anything configured to view/record those messages. It should not stop your code from working properly. If you want to see the log messages on screen: `import logging; logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)` or some other combination. Research python's builtin logging.

Comment: @daveydave400 thanks for replying! I Don't really know.. when I run my python code, it should give the valua I send via pubnub, but instead it just stops the program and shows me that sentence.

Comment: hey did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

I had to initialize my own handlers for the pubnub loggger

```
import logging

# Avoid logger Errors and register your own logger

# create logger with pubnub
logger = logging.getLogger('pubnub')

logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)  # set to other levels in different environments ie (test / prod)

# create file handler which logs even debug messages
fh = logging.FileHandler('pubnub.log')
fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
# register your handler to pubnub log
logger.addHandler(fh)
```